# sap.m.OverflowToolbar: Move Text or Label into Overflow Area

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to put `sap.m.Text` or `sap.m.Label` in an `sap.m.OverflowToolbar` so that they can be moved into the overflow area? With buttons, it is possible that the shrank view shows three ellipses and the hidden buttons are accessible with the dropdown. If I use label or text, however, the dropdown won't show.

Comment: Workaround: it works similar with sap.ui.commons.Toolbar and sap.ui.commons.TextView

Comment: No more workarounds needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49661634/5846045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release: 1.30

https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/OverflowToolbarAssociativePopoverControls.js

```
OverflowToolbarAssociativePopoverControls._mSupportedControls = ... 

(Button, OverflowToolbarButton, CheckBox, ToggleButton, Select, ComboBox, SearchField, SegmentedButton, Input, DateTimeInput, RadioButton).
```

So it's not possible to use text or label by default.

Comment: Label is [now supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49661634/5846045).

Answer (score 1):

[As of v1.52](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/a244e457c8451e3e1f2525426ff3cea23e68a1d2), any control implementing the interface [`sap.m.IOverflowToolbarContent`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.IOverflowToolbarContent) can be moved into the the overflow area. One of such controls has been the `sap.m.Label` since [v1.54](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/7fa42f78a49efaa53ddbf78e4533df874950d874).

> [sap.m.Label](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Label.js)
>
> ```
> interfaces: [
>   // ...
>   "sap.m.IOverflowToolbarContent"
> ],
> ```

**Demo:**
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/OverflowToolbar.html

[image: SAP UI5 Overflow Toolbar supporting Label]

Also the control, to which the label is pointing via the association `labelFor`, can be moved into the overflow area too if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a sap.m.Title Object to the sap.m.OverflowToolbar#content.

Within the sap.m.Title is a property called 'text' where you can assign some text.

The sap.m.Title will automatically be shrinked or disappear if it comes to an overflow. Regarding that it is just text without any related action, there is no need to show the sap.m.Title within the overflow popup.

This refers to the SAP Fiori Gudelines.

https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design/ui-components/table-bar/

Section: Behavior&Interaction --> Overflow (Generic)
"Everything else than a button cannot move into the overflow."

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to sapui5 but maybe this code may be useful for you.

```
<footer>
        <OverflowToolbar >
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <Button type="Accept" text="Accept">
                <layoutData><OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" /></layoutData>
            </Button>
            <Button type="Reject" text="Reject">
                <layoutData><OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" /></layoutData>
            </Button>
            <Button type="Accept" text="Accept">
                <layoutData><OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" /></layoutData>
            </Button>
            <Button type="Reject" text="Reject">
                <layoutData>
                    <OverflowToolbarLayoutData priority="Low" />
                </layoutData>
            </Button>
        </OverflowToolbar>
    </footer>
```

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]